# How to replace matched characters with a same number of spaces

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript and looking for a regex which can replace a matched string with the same number of space. For example, I want to match a string which begins with `show` and ends to the end of line, this is the regex I am using `/show .*$/`. If users type `show dbs` then I want to replace with  (8 spaces). How can I know the number of characters for the matched string?

Comment: Will you always be replacing the entire string, or just part of it? You can use [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to get a certain number of spaces either way.

Comment: How can know the count of spaces I need to replace?

Comment: Strings have a [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use .length on the matched element. For example

```
var pat = /show .*$/
'show dbs'.match(pat)[0].length
```

will return 8 then you can either concatenate the returned value or use .replace() on it

```
'show dbs'.replace(/^/, " ".repeat(8)) //we got 8 from the length property
```

Note:  if there are multiple matches you'll have to loop over them

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most concise way to achieve such results in javascript with RegEx is to match one part of the string, replace the rest with spaces and concatenate both parts as follows:

```
str.replace(/^(show)(.*)/, (str, p1, p2) => p1 + p2.replace(/./g, " "));
```

The first replace will separate the beginning from the end and send those parts as arguments into the method. The first part can be left untouched and the second part transformed into spaces.

Comment: Nice and elegant :) +1. Edited your code just trying to improve a bit, hope you don't mind.